# How to Change Content When User Selected Different Option From DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have a dropdownlist for user to select the item they want to retrieve from a gridview. (See Below:)

[image]

Let's say at first when the page is loaded, the dropdown list is "Item1" being displayed as the default option. So at first when the page is loaded, I should retrieve Item1 content based on ListItem Text, not value,  and display Item1 content on the webpage. If the user clicked on a different option (e.g. Item2), then I will retrieve Item2 content based on ListItem Text, and display Item2 content on the webpage, and so on..

DropDownList Code:

```
            <asp:Dropdownlist ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="136px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="jobRun_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:Dropdownlist>
```

DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged code:

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(1stListBox.SelectedValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(2ndListBox.SelectedValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(3rdListBox.SelectedValue)
              && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(4thListBox.SelectedValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(5thListBox.SelectedValue))
            {
                1stListBox_LABEL.Text = string.Empty;
                2ndListBox_LABEL.Text = string.Empty;
                3rdListBox_LABEL.Text = string.Empty;
                4thListBoxLABEL.Text = string.Empty;
                5thListBox_LABEL.Text = string.Empty;
                BindDropDownList1();
            }
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(1stListBox.SelectedValue))
                {
                    1stListBox_LABEL.Text = ("Please select at least one option").ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    1stListBox_LABEL.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(1stListBox.SelectedValue))
                {
                    1stListBox_LABEL.Text = ("Please select at least one option").ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    1stListBox_LABEL.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                if (2ndListBox.SelectedValue == String.Empty)
                {
                    2ndListBox_LABEL.Text = ("Please select at least one option").ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    2ndListBox_LABEL.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                if (3rdListBox.SelectedValue == String.Empty)
                {
                    3rdListBox_LABEL.Text = ("Please select at least one option").ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    3rdListBox_LABEL.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                if (4thListBox.SelectedValue == String.Empty)
                {
                    4thListBox_LABEL.Text = ("Please select at least one option").ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    4thListBox.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }

            AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer();
            container.ID = "TabContainer";
            container.EnableViewState = false;
            container.Tabs.Clear();
            container.Height = Unit.Pixel(2000);
            container.Width = Unit.Pixel(1200);
            container.Tabs.AddAt(0, GetManualTab());
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            img.ID = "HEATMAP";
            img.Width = 40;
            img.Height = 300;
            img.ImageUrl = "Image/HEATMAP.png";

            string selectedValue= DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            if (1stListBox.SelectedValue == "Select All")
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in 1stListBox.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Value.Equals("1"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Label tabContent = new Label();
                    tabContent.ID += item.Value;
                    tabContent.Text += item.Value;

                    string itemSelected = 1stListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    TextBox1.Text = tabContent.Text.ToString();

                    DataTable tg = new DataTable();
                    DataRow dr;
                    tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DATE"));
                    tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("STATUS", typeof(string)));
                    tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TITLE", typeof(string)));
                    tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NAME", typeof(string)));
                    tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MAX", typeof(int)));
                    tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MIN", typeof(int)));
                    tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AVG", typeof(int)));
                    tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PERCENTILE25", typeof(int)));
                    tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PERCENTILE50", typeof(int)));
                    tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PERCENTILE75", typeof(int)));
                    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
                    { 
                        if (gvr.Cells[2].Text == tabContent.Text.ToString() && gvr.Cells[0].Text == selectedValue.ToString())
                        {
                            dr = tg.NewRow();
                            dr["DATE"] = gvr.Cells[0].Text;
                            dr["STATUS"] = gvr.Cells[1].Text;
                            dr["TITLE"] = gvr.Cells[2].Text;
                            dr["NAME"] = gvr.Cells[3].Text;
                            dr["MAX"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[4].Text);
                            dr["MIN"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[5].Text);
                            dr["AVG"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[6].Text);
                            dr["PERCENTILE25"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[7].Text);
                            dr["PERCENTILE50"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[8].Text);
                            dr["PERCENTILE75"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[9].Text);
                            tg.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }

                    Chart Chart1= new Chart();
                    Chart1.DataSource = tg;
                    Chart1.Width = 600;
                    Chart1.Height = 350;

                    Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
                    Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
                    List<object> lst = tg.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

                    foreach (DataRow row in tg.Rows)
                        Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["Status"], new object[] { row["MAX"], row["MIN"], row["AVG"], row["PERCENTILE25"], row["PERCENTILE50"], row["PERCENTILE75"] });
                    Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;

                    if (tg.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string title = (tg.Rows[0]["TITLE"].ToString());
                        Chart1.Titles.Add(title);
                    }
                    //create chartareas
                    ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
                    //ca.Name = "ChartArea3";
                    ca.AxisX = new Axis();
                    ca.AxisY = new Axis();
                    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

                    //databind
                    Chart1.DataBind();
                    Chart1.Visible = true;

                    AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                    panel.HeaderText += item.Text;
                    container.Tabs.Add(panel);
                    panel.Controls.Add(Chart1);

                                  }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in 1stListBox.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                    {
                        Label tabContent = new Label();
                        tabContent.ID += item.Value;
                        tabContent.Text += item.Value;

                        //string itemSelected = 1stListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        TextBox1.Text = tabContent.Text.ToString();

                        DataTable tg = new DataTable();
                        DataRow dr;
                        tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DATE"));
                        tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("STATUS", typeof(string)));
                        tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TITLE", typeof(string)));
                        tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NAME", typeof(string)));
                        tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MAX", typeof(int)));
                        tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MIN", typeof(int)));
                        tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AVG", typeof(int)));
                        tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PERCENTILE25", typeof(int)));
                        tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PERCENTILE50", typeof(int)));
                        tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PERCENTILE75", typeof(int)));
                        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
                        {
                            if (gvr.Cells[2].Text == tabContent.Text.ToString())
                            {
                                dr = tg.NewRow();
                                dr["DATE"] = gvr.Cells[0].Text;
                                dr["STATUS"] = gvr.Cells[1].Text;
                                dr["TITLE"] = gvr.Cells[2].Text;
                                dr["NAME"] = gvr.Cells[3].Text;
                                dr["MAX"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[4].Text);
                                dr["MIN"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[5].Text);
                                dr["AVG"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[6].Text);
                                dr["PERCENTILE25"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[7].Text);
                                dr["PERCENTILE50"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[8].Text);
                                dr["PERCENTILE75"] = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[9].Text);
                                tg.Rows.Add(dr);
                            }
                        }

                        Chart chart1= new Chart();
                        chart1.DataSource = tg;
                        chart1.Width = 600;
                        chart1.Height = 350;

                        chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
                        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
                        List<object> lst = tg.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

                        foreach (DataRow row in tg.Rows)
                            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["Status"], new object[] { row["MAX"], row["MIN"], row["AVG"], row["PERCENTILE25"], row["PERCENTILE50"], row["PERCENTILE75"] });
                        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;

                        if (tg.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            string title = (tg.Rows[0]["TITLE"].ToString());
                            chart1.Titles.Add(title);
                        }
                        //create chartareas
                        ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
                        //ca.Name = "ChartArea3";
                        ca.AxisX = new Axis();
                        ca.AxisY = new Axis();
                        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

                        //databind
                        chart1.DataBind();
                        chart1.Visible = true;

                        AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                        panel.HeaderText += item.Value;
                        container.Tabs.Add(panel);
                        //panel.Controls.Add(tabContent);
                        panel.Controls.Add(chart1);
                       }
                }
            }
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(container);
        }
```

BindDropDownList1() Method:

```
       public void BindDropDownList1()
    {
               //Lost to hold the values
        List<DateTime> listCopy = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime dt;
        string values = String.Join(", ", JOBRUN_CBL.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Text));
        if (values.Contains("Select All"))
        {
            //Loop through each items in listbox and then add it to list
            foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (DateTime.TryParse(li.Text, out dt))
                {
                    listCopy.Add(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Loop through each items in listbox and then add it to list
            foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                //check if item is selected
                if (li.Selected == true)
                {
                    //add items to list
                    listCopy.Add(DateTime.Parse(li.Text));
                }
            }
        }

        //compare and sort so that the latest date comes on top
        listCopy.Sort((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x));
        //clear the items in dropdownlist
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
        //set the datasource to dropdownlist
        DropDownList1.DataSource = listCopy;
        //set the dateformatstring in dropdownlist
        DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}";
        //Bind the dropdownlist
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
```

When the user **clicked** on a **different** option from the dropdownlist, how do I get what is being **clicked** from the DropDownList (based on ListItem **Text** (e.g. Item 2), **not** value (e.g. 1), then retrieve data from gridview based on what is being clicked, and display a **different** content on the webpage based on what is being clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `autopostback` and `selectedindexchanged event` to do that.

As per the code below:
If you want this to trigger on `Page_Load` you might want to call the event on `Page_Load` or you bind the first item to your `gridview`.

.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" 
AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem>Test 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Test 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Test 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Test 4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

.cs

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddl.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        // Get your selected Text
        string value = ddl.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();

        // Do your binding here


    }
}
```

Comment: hi this is a c# question. Thanks for your help! but I wonder why when I select a different option nothing appeared. I was supposed to display 1st option content when the page first load. Then if the user selected a different option, I am supposed to get the option text and retrieve values from gridview. Then display them out. But when I tried to select a different option from gridview, nothing appeared...do u know why that's the case?

Comment: u mean if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(1stListBox.SelectedValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(2ndListBox.SelectedValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(3rdListBox.SelectedValue)
              && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(4thListBox.SelectedValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(5thListBox.SelectedValue))
            {
                1stListBox_LABEL.Text = string.Empty;
                 ....
                BindDropDownList1();
            } ? may I know how does that affect the dropdown?

Comment: sorry @nicholas! I could not discuss with u in chat because I got access denied. I think I shall delete my previous comment instead.

Comment: hi @nicholas, after I took out the rebind sentence, I think it works!! Thanks for your help and reply! Really appreciate it! Your solution is great! :)

Comment: Oh great... I thought wanted to ask you post the GridView html code as well..But since it work then is ok

Comment: hahaha..wow thanks you are so helpful! I think I am lucky that you have noticed my post! :)

Comment: Anyway next time you should post more what is the expected result you want... Because with the image and html dropdown code we don't really know how to help you with so little information